# await Promise.resolve of object returning undefined?

Tags: node.js, typescript

So I'm trying to store a value as a promise, however I am running into an issue: the object, which is defined before the Promise.resolve, is undefined after it is awaited. The workflow is as such:

```
console.log(user); // Prints out full user. Yay!
migration.user = Promise.resolve(user);
console.log(migration.user); // Promise { <pending> }
console.log(await migration.user); // undefined
```

Does anyone know what could cause this to happen?

Comment: Works just fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/r08zkrmr/

Comment: Are you inside an `async` function?

Comment: Any chance your `user` has a `then` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @Bergi solved the issue. To look how that could have happened, see that example.

```
Promise.resolve({then:f=>f()}).then(e=>console.log(e))
```

Even if your object is not `undefined`, the `.resolve` calls the `then` function with a callback and then you get the result of the `then` function and not the object itself back.

Have a look at the `Promise.resolve` description and the `thenable` [for example here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).